# Bootstrap popover do not display <input>, <button> etc

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, popover

can someone help me to figure this one out:

html:

```
 <a href="#" class="form-control input-sm"  data-original-title="Uploaded Files:" data-content="@include('uploadedFiles')">Show Files</a>
```

@include file:

```
@foreach($apply->invoice as $invoice)
    @if(str_limit($invoice['file_name'], 9,'') == 'popUpload')
        <a href='{{url($site . '/pop/' . array_get($invoice, 'file_name'))}}'> 
 {{array_get($invoice, 'file_name')}}</a>
    @else
        <a href='{{url($site . '/pop/' . array_get($invoice, 'file_name'))}}' download> 
{{array_get($invoice, 'file_name')}}</a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

My JQuery:

```
    var options = {

        html: true,
        placement: 'bottom',
    };

    $('a').popover(options);

    $('html').on('click', function(e) {
          if (typeof $(e.target).data('original-title') == 'undefined' &&
              !$(e.target).parents().is('.popover.in')) {
             $('[data-original-title]').popover('hide');
         }
    });
```

What it should do is to list all uploaded files and it does. The problem is that i can't place any "button", "input" etc on my html file. For ex i want to put "delete" button near every listed file and it's not displayed. Can any one tell me what's going on? One more thing, the "a href" download parameter doesn't work.

Comment: Can you check your mark down. I expect there is a tag missing in this sentence "The problem is that i can't place any , etc on my html file"

Comment: I corrected by post. Should be understandable now. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, problem solved. Just need to add to my JS sanitize: false

Comment: Reply with the answer you found and mark it as the solution. That will help others that have a similar issue in the future.